# Animating an NSView frame, then jumping to specific frame

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, nsviewanimation

I'm trying to slide a gridded `NSView` up, revealing another row from another `NSView`. Then, once the animation is done, the second `NSView` will dissapear, and the first will immediately move back to its original position with the new data.

It works 4/5s of the time. The only error I'm getting is when the first view doesn't reset to the original position; it stays were the animation finishes.

Here's the basic idea (I don't have the code here):

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    [[myView animator] setFrame:newPos];
} completionHandler:^{
    [myView setFrame:originalPos];
}];
```

I'm having trouble Googling since `runAnimationGroup:completionHandler` is new in Lion.

Comment: I could just switch the code around, but I'm interested in why this doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a threaded race condition. Is there any way to prevent it?